# Convert basic time chosen into date table for Corona local notifications

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Looking to set up local notifications at certain times set by the user in my Corona app.  I have the basic notification working, using the following guide:
http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/index/systemschedulenotification

```
local utcTime = os.date( "!*t", os.time() + 60 )
local notification = system.scheduleNotification( utcTime, options )
```

But I want to take the time chosen by the user, and construct a date table in coordinatedUniversalTime format, to take the place of the os.time() + 60 part of the above code.  Anyone know how to do that?

My time picker is returning a basic hour and minute value, and if it's AM or PM.

Thanks!

Comment: Found this date module which I'll try out tonight.  http://math2.org/luasearch-2/luadist-extract/luadate-2.dist/luadate-2.src/date.doc.htm

Answer (score 0):

Right, got it, it was easy.

```
local options = {
           alert = "Alert Text",
           sound = "audio/sound.caf"
        }

        local currentDate = os.date( "*t" )
        local notificationHr
        if reminderPicker1.getAMPM() == "am" then
            notificationHr = reminderPicker1.getHour()
        else
            notificationHr = reminderPicker1.getHour() + 12
        end
        local utcTime = os.date( "!*t", os.time{year=currentDate.year, month=currentDate.month, day=currentDate.day, hour=notificationHr, min=reminderPicker1.getMin(), sec=0 } )
        local notification = system.scheduleNotification( utcTime, options )
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer since it solved your problem. This will improve SO knowledge base.

Comment: This helped me. But I got lots more help here: https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/59921-get-local-notification-daily-and-weekly-between-2-dates/ And be careful with this code, because 12 is a special exception. If you add 12 to 12PM you will be at 24 which is actually midnight. If you leave 12AM without adding 12 to it, you will stay at 12 which is actually noon.